# JavaScriptでUTF-16でCSVファイルをダウンロード対応したい

Tags: javascript, csv, 文字コード

CSVダウンロードをJavaScriptでやりたいと思っています。

「UTF-16 BOMあり」に対応したいのですが、実際下のコードで対応できたファイルを見ると文字コードがhexedicimelで、中身が000になってしまいどうもできていないようです。
どこが悪いのか知りたいです。

```
function exportCSV(records) {
   let data = records.map((record)=>record.join('\t')}).join('\r\n');
   csv_string = "\ufeff" + data; //UTF-16

    var array = [];
    for (var i=0; i<csv_string.length; i++){
     array.push(csv_string.charCodeAt(i));
    }
   var csv_contents = new Uint16Array(array);

   var blob = new Blob([csv_contents] , {
                                type: "text/csv;charset=utf-16;"
   });
   let url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = 'result.csv';
   link.href = url;
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

手元の環境で下記のコードをUTF-8で保存して実行したところ、正常にUTF-16 LE BOMとしてTSVファイルを出力できました。

ご質問のコードは`record.join('\t')}`に`}`が付いていて実行できないなど、本来のコードと異なるようですので、サンプルコード作成時に書き換えて削った箇所に原因があるかもしれません。

データ付きで単体動作する[再現可能な短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)となるように質問文を編集していただけますでしょうか。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>サンプル</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function exportCSV(records) {
   let data = records.map((record)=>record.join('\t')).join('\r\n');
   csv_string = "\ufeff" + data; //UTF-16

    var array = [];
    for (var i=0; i<csv_string.length; i++){
     console.log(csv_string[i]);
     array.push(csv_string.charCodeAt(i));
    }
   var csv_contents = new Uint16Array(array);

   var blob = new Blob([csv_contents] , {
                                type: "text/csv;charset=utf-16;" 
   });
   let url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = 'result.csv';
   link.href = url;
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);
};

rs = [["a", "b", "c"],
      ["A", "B", "C"],
      ["い", "ろ", "は"]];
exportCSV(rs);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。